# why dose the first loop always runs faster than the second one?

Tags: c++

especially,the larger the number of cycles is,the more obvious the difference becomes.

test in g++ without optimization

```cpp
int main()
{
  int a[]={0,0};
  int b[]={0,0};
  //first loop
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<0x00FFFFFF;i++)
  {
     a[0]++;a[1]++; 
  }

  //second loop
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<0x00FFFFFF;i++)
  {
     b[0]++;b[0]++; //yes it's b[0] not b[1]
  }

  return 0;
}
```

> Somebody may not believe me,me either.But in this code the first loop is at least two times faster than the second one.

Comment: and i have seen the Disassemble of code,they are exacly the same.code is  compiled in Debug mode in visual studio2015

Comment: The second one updates `b[0]` both times, not `b[1]`. Is that intentional?

Comment: I'd expect a good optimizer to remove the loops entirely, and just set the variables to the final result.

Comment: @Barmar yes,that's the difference which causes the difference,but i don't know why.Very confusing,does this problem has something to do with cpu?

Comment: @Barmar yes,a optimizer could remove this loop.but that make this question seems meaningless to some extent.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry i forget the ';',but i think i've stated my question clearly.

Comment: Why are you asking about the performance of **code compiled in debug mode**? This does not make any sense at all. Code compiled in debug mode is intended for reliable debugging, not performance.

Comment: @MichaelGeary because in **release mode,the loop will be removed**,and the  assemble code directly gives you  the result of a[0] b[0],which makes this question meaningless

Comment: @bigxiao What makes this question meaningless - is the comparison of performance, of code compiled in debug mode (for the reasons, already explained, above).

Comment: Then it's a meaningless question. If you compile code in debug mode, you can't expect any particular performance characteristics from it. That's not the purpose of debug mode. The purpose is reliable debugging of your C/C++ code in a way that matches the source code, not performance. What is the point of this exercise? What are you trying to find out?

Comment: My last comment probably sounded hot-headed; my apology! I only meant to say that debug mode is meant for debugging, and release mode is meant for performance. I'm all for talking about performance issues and trying to understand what makes for fast code and slow code. But worrying about the performance of a debug build is like asking "why is my release build hard to debug?" :-)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Debug mode may not represent the real performance exactly,but that does not mean this question is meaningless.Have you ever try this code in g++ without optimization?The first loop is still two times faster.

Comment: @MichaelGeary i get your point.maybe i should use g++ as complier,but whatever compiler i use,the question is still there,the run time is still quite different,and that's what i want to figure out.

Comment: "_Debug mode may not represent the real performance exactly_" 1) Debug mode does not represent the real performance, **at all**, due to it not being optimized, at all. 2) Where did I say, anything, relating to compiler being used? What I (and many others) stated are compiler-agnostic.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: "Debug mode" and "release mode" are really two very vague terms. It's better to be precise and talk about specific compiler and linker options; are we talking about the `NDEBUG` macro (which can even be enabled and disabled per compilation unit!), different runtimes, different optimisation settings, or even something else? Whether you do or do not ship with those things enabled or disabled depends on the goals and requirements of your specific project.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i mentioned complier because the vs2015 IDE has only Debug or Release(optimized mode)mode,so i use the g++ instead to show the **real performace**,that's why i mentioned g++.Where did i say the result  differs relating to complier being used?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I was using "Debug mode" as a shorthand for "compilation without any optimizations", hence I didn't use a term of "Release mode", since it is VS specific.

Comment: @bigxiao So, when checking said "real performance", you did enable optimizations (`-O3`), right? Otherwise - the comparison of performance is just as useless.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: AFAIK, "Debug mode" in GCC usually refers to a libstdc++ version with more runtime checks: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i'm confused that why **performance** make sense only in optimized option?I'm just comparing the run time of two loops in their origin form,dose that goes wrong?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius if compiled in -o3,then the two loops both cost 0ms,becase there is actually no loop.I'm not interested in their "best performce",i'm interested in their performance in current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's a pipelining issue. In the first loop you're writing to two different memory locations, so the second addition doesn't need to wait for the first one to finish, and the CPU can do both at once.

In the second loop, you're incrementing the same variable both times, so the second one has to wait for the first one to finish. This slows down the pipeline.

Comment: That seems reasonable.But the Disassamble of two loops are the same,does that means CPU do not execute the assemble code line by line?

Comment: In the assemble code,it dosen't do both at once.That's confusing.

Comment: Pipelining is done automatically by the CPU, it doesn't appear in the code.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i think i have to study the pipeline mechanism before i figure it out.